# CSS image stuck at corner

Tags: html, css

In this photo I added a div *arrow* using CSS I turned it into an arrow. In the center of the div/arrow i need to put an image.

[image]

This icon inside the grid is not changing the position to center without disturbing the css of the arrow created using grid.

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E6EAEF;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  /* tweaked this */
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid #E6EAEF;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin: -5px 10px 0 5px;
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin: -5px 0 0 0;
}

.arrow-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <img class="arrow-icon" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/magnifying-glass-icon-13.png" alt="">
</div>
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the image has no action purpose, such as click events, and is for display purposes only, you can place it in the background.

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  /* All background properties are combined in here. */
  /* The CALC() is just to nudge it to the right so it looks better on the arrow. */
  background: #E6EAEF url(https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/magnifying-glass-icon-13.png) calc(50% + 4px) 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 17px; /* Sets the icon size. */
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  /* tweaked this */
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  width: 50px;
}

.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: -20px;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid #E6EAEF;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin: -5px 10px 0 5px;
}

.arrow::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin: -5px 0 0 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
</div>
```

Comment: This is making the icon above the arrow but it is affecting the arrows

Comment: @VaranshuAgrawal The arrow was a different CSS problem. Fixed it now :)

Comment: Thank You, Is there any way i can create multiple arrows with icon but using different images but using same classes

Comment: @VaranshuAgrawal In short, yes. You can add another class that will determine the icon type. like `.arrow.search { background-image: url(...); }`.
Another way, depends on you page structure. you can write a selector that will target each separate arrow and change the background-image

Answer (score 1):

You can set `position: absolute;` to `.arrow-icon` and then center it with `top: 50%; left: 50%;`. Translate is required to center the center of image.

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E6EAEF;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  /* tweaked this */
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid #E6EAEF;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin: -5px 10px 0 5px;
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin: -5px 0 0 0;
}

.arrow-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 15px !important;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;   /*The Icon was overlapped by some part of arrow*/
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <img class="arrow-icon" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/search-512.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Better use flexbox to center

Comment: @Sfili_81 Yeah, I could have, but didn't wanted much to interfere with OP's code. So, I left it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:grid` and `place-items:center` this CSS property will center the search icon.

```css
.arrow{
  margin:50px 100px;
  background:#e6e9ee;
  height:50px;
  width:80px;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:10px;
}

.arrow::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border-width:25px 15px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#e6e9ee;
  border-top-color:transparent;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  right:-30px;
}

.arrow::before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border-width:25px 15px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fff;
  border-top-color:transparent;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <img class="arrow-icon" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/search-512.png" height="20">
</div>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer, so anybody know how to solve th OP question